# Pandas: apply function pairwise to a dataframe and a panel

Tags: pandas, covariance, finance, portfolio

In the context of finance, suppose there is a dataframe of asset weights and a panel of daily covariance matrix:

```
w = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01','2016-01-02','2016-01-03']),'A1':[0.3,0.1,0.1],'A2':[0.4,0.4,0.4]}).set_index(['Date'])
covar = [[[0.000087,0.000017],[0.000087,0.000017],[0.000087,0.000017]],[[0.000017,0.00019],[0.000017,0.00019],[0.000017,0.00019]]]
covPanel = pd.Panel(covar, items=['A1', 'A2'],  major_axis=pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01','2016-01-02','2016-01-03']), minor_axis=['A1', 'A2'])
```

To calculate the 1-day portfolio variance, the below function can be used:

```
def portVar(w,sigma):
    return w.dot(sigma.dot(w))
```

I can apply the last row of weights to the covariance matrix each day to get daily variance:

```
out = covPanel.apply(lambda cov1: portVar(w.iloc[-1,:],cov1),axis = [2,0])
```

But how do I apply the above function to the dataframe and covariance matrix pairwise, for every day (without loop)?

In other words, something like:

```
pd.ApplyPairwise(portVar,w,covPanel)
```

and return the daily variance just as "out" above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***option 1***
rewrite `portVar`

pass entire panel to the function being applied and use `xs` to get the appropriate cross section for that particular date's weight.  The date is in the `name` attribute.

---

```
def portVar(w, sigma):
    s = sigma.xs(w.name, axis='major')
    return w.dot(s.dot(w))

w.apply(portVar, 1, sigma=covPanel)

Date
2016-01-01    0.000042
2016-01-02    0.000033
2016-01-03    0.000033
dtype: float64
```

***option 2***
`numpy` broadcasting

```
cv = covPanel.values
wv = w.values

pd.Series(((wv[None, :] * cv).sum(-1).T * wv).sum(1), w.index)

Date
2016-01-01    0.000042
2016-01-02    0.000033
2016-01-03    0.000033
dtype: float64
```

---

***response to comment***

A generic python way to do things pair wise is `zip`
I'll use a list comprehension to produce a the list we're looking for.  Note the transpose on the panel object to ensure the dates are the first dimension.

```
def portVar(w,sigma):
    return w.dot(sigma.dot(w))

[portVar(w_, s_) for w_, s_ in zip(w.values, covPanel.transpose(1, 0, 2).values)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'd prefer option 1 in this case. Do you also know of something more generic in python of applying a function pairwise on two "lists" of elements?

Comment: @iwbabn I've updated my post.  Hopefully this is useful.